# Как использовать return в java?

Tags: java, return

Вот вроде понимаю что `return` что-то возвращает, завершает процессы метода (функции), но что, как он это делает вообще, не понимаю.
Пересмотрел кучу статей, видио по этому поводу, всё равно не понимаю!!!

Если не сложно приведите пример чтобы понял, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Каждый метод - это кусок последовательно выполняющегося кода.

Каждый метод в своей сигнатуре (определении) имеет указание на тип возвращаемого значения.

Каждый метод всегда заканчивается вызовом `return`. В случае если метод возвращаемым значением имеет `void` (не путать с `Void`) то ключевое слово `return` можно (и нужно) опустить. 
Пример:

```
public void method(){
    //в данном случае return можно опустить
    return;
}
```

Также return в этих методах можно использовать для логических целей. Например не выполнять код  методе, если какие-то условия не выполнились

```
public void method(){
    //не выполнять код метода далее, если системное время меньше 0
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() < 0){
        return;
    }
    //системное время больше нуля, продолжаем выполнение
    //опять таки return можно здесь не вызывать, он и так по умолчанию подразумевается в конце кода метода.
}
```

Если возвращаемое значение метода не `void` то метод обязан вызвать `return` и вернуть значение указанного типа. Его можно использовать для назначения к-л переменно или иначе использовать
Пример:

```
int i = getInt();

public int getInt() {
    return 42;
    //т.к. возвращаемое значение int, то нельзя вернуть не int
    //return "42" - не скомпилируется, т.к. возврашать метод должен int, не String
}
```

В последнем случае результат работы метода будет присвоен переменной `i`

Answer (score 2):

Не могу говорить совершенно точно про java, но думаю, что там все работает также, как и в C\С++.

Если я правильно понял вопрос - отвечаю:

При вызове функции происходит смена контекста выполняемой программы - все значимые регистры и локальные переменные, а также регистр связи сохраняются в стек, а в регистры, предназначенные под передачу параметров (а если их много - для этого тоже используется стек) записываются передаваемые параметры.

Когда выполняется строка return result - в регистры, предназначенные для возврата результата выполнения функции, помещается её результат.

В случае, если результат не помещается в эти регистры - он помещается в стек, а в регистр заносится адрес возвращаемого значения в стеке.

Кроме того, после завершения функции должен быть восстановлен контекст.

А более подробно на эту тему советую почитать "Соглашение о вызовах" целевой платформы.